# Regex to replace string between dashes (groovy)

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a method in groovy that receives a string in the following format:

```
def src = "a.b.c-constant-qualifier"
def update = "test"
```

I am trying to come up with a regex that will replace the stuff between -???- with the updated string. In the above case the result should be:

String result= "a.b.c-test-qualifier"

I currently do:

```
def update ="-test-" 
def src = "a.b.c-constant-qualifier"
def result = (src =~ /-constant-/).replaceFirst(update)
```

Which works as long as the source string contains the `"-constant-"` string. But how do I make my regex work so it replaces anything between two dashes with the update string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this instead:

```
def update ="-test-"
def src = "a.b.c-constant-qualifier"
def result = (src =~ /-[^-]*-/).replaceFirst(update)
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/rZ3nJ0